# RewriteCond redirect a domain to another except for one script, do the opposite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

1) in general, I want everything on www.ABC.com to be redirected to www.XYZ.com

2) *EXCEPT* when it's 
www.ABC.com/this/123([a-z]+).html 
... it must Rewrite (NOT redirect) to ... 
www.ABC.com/that_script.php?var=123

3) Also *EXCEPT*: when it's 
www.XYZ.com/this/123([a-z]+).html 
... it must go (redirect) to ....
www.ABC.com/this/123([a-z]+).html
(so the 2nd rule will apply after that)

*EDIT* Both domains parked on the same hosting, so sharing the same HTACCESS

*EDIT2* Language of the project is PHP

---

I tried various RewriteCond with %{REQUEST_URI} or %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} but it never works, either saying it's an infinite loop or simply don't take the condition at all.

---

*EDIT3* In PHP, it would looks like that...

```
if( FALSE !== strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'ABC.com') && FALSE !== strstr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 'that_script') ) {
    header("Location: http://www.XYZ.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],TRUE,301);
}
if( FALSE !== strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'XYZ.com') && FALSE === strstr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 'that_script') ) {
    header("Location: http://www.ABC.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],TRUE,301);
}
```

I want this, but in HTACCESS

Comment: I have the answer. I'll need a couple of minutes to check my code. ;)

Comment: Forgot to mention both domains are parked to the same hosting, so sharing the HTACCESS of course

Comment: Are those on seperate servers or directories at least?

Comment: yeah, basically all the script files are on the root of the same server.  the /this/ part isn't a physical directory.

Comment: Just btw isn't it easier to redirect using html meta refresh or http header?

Comment: Html meta no!  http header I don't mind if you provide a working code!  But I'd really prefer to get the rewriteCond answer, for the sake of the community reading this post in the future

Comment: I just gave it a thought. You can't use thie .htaccess especially it's ModRewrite 'cos it's meant to redirect the request to a different file. It doesn't really redirect you to another domain. It will be a lot easier with headers. What language are you writing your app on?

Comment: I think it can work...  Because the basic domain redirect works (those 2 lines):

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ABC\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.XYZ.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9811/discussion-between-itehnological-disexisting-and-ecchymose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect www.xyz.com/this/123([a-z]+).html to www.abc.com/that_script.php?var=123
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xyz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^this/(123)[a-z]+\.html$ http://www.abc.com/that_script.php?var=$1 [R,L,NC]

# Forward www.abc.com/this/123([a-z]+).html to www.abc.com/that_script.php?var=123
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^this/(123)[a-z]+\.html$ that_script.php?var=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Redirect abc.com to www.xyz.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.xyz.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Change all `R` to `R=301` once you have verified that it is all working fine.

Also note that I have used first RewriteRule in a way to avoid 1 extra forward (RewriteRule # 2 above).

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have above, it will be something to the effect of:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ReWriteRule ^/this/([a-z0-9]+).html www.ABC.com/that_script.php?var=$1 [PT,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.ABC.com$ [NC]
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$  www.XYZ.com [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This will do the following -

1 - Any traffic hitting `http://www.ABC.com/this/<Anything made of Numbers and Letters>` will pass through to `http://www.ABC.com/that_script.php?var=<Anything made of Numbers and Letters>` while continuing to say `http://www.ABC.com/this/<Anything made of Numbers and Letters>` to the visitor.

2 - Any traffic hitting anything other than what is referenced to #1 will be redirected to www.XYZ.com with a HTTP code of 301 (Moved Permanently).

Remember that you have to be able to put mod_rewrite rules in your .htaccess files. Having the option of `AllowOverride FileInfo` for the directory would make sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the official documentation about [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) ? All the information you need is in the manual, there is no secret.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect www.xyz.com/this/123([a-z]+).html to www.abc.com/this/123([a-z]+).html.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.xyz.com$ [AND]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/this/123([a-z]+).html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite www.abc.com/this/123([a-z]+).html to www.abc.com/that_script.php?var=123.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/this/123([a-z]+)\.html$ /that_script.php?var=123 [L]

# Redirect everything else to www.xyz.com.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your first 3 lines, following this comment -- 
# Redirect www.xyz.com/this/123([a-z]+).html to www.abc.com/this/123([a-z]+).html -- 

causes an error 500
(I replaced the values with the real ones, of course)